# How do I call the string content of a variable containing a filepath instead of the file at the end of the filepath? Bash/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I want to give a script a file path, take the file name, assign the file name to a variable, then perform an action to the file at the file path.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to access the string content of the variable, instead of the file being held at the file path.

TestingScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

egrep -o "[^/]+$" ${1} #get name of the file from the end of the filepath
wc -l $1 #count the number of lines in the file
```

Testing.txt

```
This
/is
the
text
```

**Running it:**

```
./TestingScript.sh "/User/Me/Directory/Testing.txt"
```

Instead of this returning:

```
Testing.txt
4 /User/Me/Directory/Testing.txt
```

This is the output:

```
/is
4 /User/Me/Directory/Testing.txt
```

Comment: `echo "$1" | grep -E -o '^/.+'` would run `grep -E` (aka `egrep`) on the name, but the regex doesn't match the last component of the name (you'd need `'[^/]+$'` for that).  But the command you want is `basename $1` (not least because `basename /x/y/z/` reports `z` and even the revised `grep` regex fails on that).  The `-o` option to `grep` (`egrep`) is a GNU extension, incidentally.

Comment: Yea, `echo "$1" | grep -E -o '[^/]+$'` is right or `ls $1 |  grep -E -o '[^/]+$'` and your `basename` way also works ( `basename $1 | egrep -o'[^/]+$'` )  Sorry I was being dumb and not understanding the programing language. I have been so used to R.

Comment: ohhh, you can also do basename $1 alone. ok

Comment: why does this matter " The -o option to grep (egrep) is a GNU extension, incidentally."

Comment: I did not have an issue with `'[^/]+$'` ... whhy do you say it fails? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Not all copies of `grep` on the machines I use are GNU `grep` — all the world is not a Linux box.  And you would either get an error message or different behaviour if the version of `grep` on the non-Linux box either does not support the `-o` option at all or does not use the option with the same meaning as GNU `grep` does.  If you only work on Linux boxes, you don't have to worry about it; that's why it was an incidental comment.

Comment: `echo /x/y/z/ | grep -o -E '[^/]+$'` gives no output.  If there is no trailing slash (which is used to force the name to be a directory), then there's no problem.  It's a case of extremism — how can your script be broken by extreme inputs.  If `/x/y/z/` was a directory, the `wc` would fail too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

Running `echo "$1" | grep -E -o '^/.+`' would run `grep -E` (aka `egrep`) on the name, but the regex doesn't match the last component of the name (you'd need `'[^/]+$'` for that, and the name couldn't end with a `/`). But the command you want is `basename $1` (not least because `basename /x/y/z/` reports `z` and even the revised `grep` regex fails on that). Incidentally, the `-o` option to `grep` (`egrep`) is a GNU extension.

> Why does this matter *"The `-o` option to `grep` (`egrep`) is a GNU extension"*?

Not all copies of `grep` on the machines I use are GNU `grep` — all the world is not a Linux box. And you would either get an error message or different behaviour if the version of `grep` on the non-Linux box either does not support the `-o` option at all or does not use the option with the same meaning as GNU `grep` does. If you only work on Linux boxes, you don't have to worry about it; that's why it was an incidental comment.

> I did not have an issue with `'[^/]+$'` — why do you say it fails?

Because `echo /x/y/z/ | grep -o -E '[^/]+$'` gives no output. If there is no trailing slash (which is used to force the name to be a directory), then there's no problem. It's a case of extremism — how can your script be broken by extreme inputs. If `/x/y/z/` was a directory (or didn't exist), the `wc` command would fail too.